# Issue picking price from webscrape Python

Tags: python, web, screen-scraping

Following guides but still unable to pick a price from a website - I want to pick the product name and product price.

I can pick the name = that comes up in console. Price returns "none". Please Nonetype error I don't where I'm going wrong.

```
page = requests.get('https://www.wickes.co.uk/search?text=brick')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
all_bricks = soup.find(class_='products-list products-list-v2')

items = all_bricks.find(class_='card product-card')
items_name = all_bricks.find(class_='product-card__title product-card__title-v2')

price_box = items.find("div", attrs={"class": "product-card__price-value "})
price = price_box
print (price)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], including the relevant part of the HTML source.

Comment: His question was meeting the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Well you have here two problems:

1. You add extra space in the class name. `BeautifulSoup` is desinged to
   trim the extra spaces in the html DOM.
2. You didn't use `.text` to get the price back.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.wickes.co.uk/search?text=brick')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
all_bricks = soup.find(class_='products-list products-list-v2')

items = all_bricks.find(class_='card product-card')
items_name = all_bricks.find(class_='product-card__title product-card__title-v2')

price_box = items.find("div", attrs={"class": "product-card__price-value"}) #Extra space removed
price = price_box.text #adding ".text"
print (price)
```

Comment: If `price_box` is `None` as claimed, then trying to print `price_box.text` certainly won't work.

Comment: He got `None` because of adding extra space to class name. The code tested and work.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the names and prices you can just search for them directly.

```
page = requests.get('https://www.wickes.co.uk/search?text=brick')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
names = [x.text.strip() for x in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'product-card__title product-card__title-v2'})]
prices = [x.text.strip() for x in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'product-card__price-value '})]
print(names[0], prices[0])
```

Comment: `IndexError: list index out of range`. You need to remove the extra space, then it will work correctly.

Comment: hi Thanks for this solution - it works - However, I must not understand how to apply the concepts --> when I try to apply this, changing the search tag and attribues, for another site, this comprehension does not work. Could you give some guidance toward resources which guide on list comprehension for such scraping activities?